# Eclipse shortcut for switching between argument of a method using tab keyboard

Tags: java, eclipse, shortcut

[image]

Hello,
i'm looking for the eclipse shortcut to show that little squares that let to navigate between arguments of a method using tab key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Window > Preferences > General  > Keys  settings in eclipse.

Here you can customize your shortcuts.

Comment: hi techprat . thanks for answering .
do you know the name of that shortcut ?

Comment: next word may be. But search for next and you will have some options. Check which you want exactly